# Is object slicing on purpose a viable technique?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a class called `AudioSample`, implementation not relevant.
AudioSamples can be loaded from multiple sources, for each source I derive a class from AudioSample that adds the relevant loader code for the source in question. After loading I slice the object on purpose by passing it on to the function that uses `AudioSample` by value.

It seems fine by me, it prevents polluting the base class with various loading functions and prevents me having to modify the (tried and tested) base class when a new loader has to be added.

However, when searching stackoverflow for object slicing I only find answers describing it as a problem and explaining it's potential pitfalls, that makes me wonder: Am I using it in a way I'n not supposed to? Will I run into potential problems by doing this I'm currently not aware off ?

Comment: How about just having a plain virtual abstract `load` function declared? The the sub-classes can implement it any way they want. Then using references or (smart) pointers you can side-step this issue completely.

Comment: Why not just create non-member load functions for various sources instead of creating new classes?

Comment: An `AudioSample` should be the result of loading an audio sample. It should not have a `load` member function. `load` should be the member function of a class like `AudioSampleLoader`, with an `AudioSample` return type. `AudioSample` itself can probably be `final`.

Comment: @VaughnCato : `AudioSample`'s state is rather complex. Having a non-member load function fill in all those private members would require adding a lot of setters which are no longer needed after loading. That seems polluting to me and exposes more then I'd like to. Making the non-member loader a friend requires modifying the class, which might not always be possible.

Comment: I would like to point one thing in your approach. Normally after loading resources you probably don't want to copy or move them in memory. But to do slicing you will need to make a copy of original object.

Comment: Every C++ programmer do slicing intentionnaly! Do not let unworries decide how rich your expressivity can be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Object slicing is not a problem per se, since it's a perfectly well-defined operation. It's just that it normally raises a "WTF" moment, because it's seldom intended. My favourity metric of code quality is the reciprocal of WTFs per minute of reading, so from this perspective, it's a bad idea because it will require heavy documentation to state "yes, I really know what I'm doing."

As such, I'd be more inclined to confine it to a well-named and well-purposed function. Something like this:

```
class AudioSampleLoadedViaFoo : public AudioSample
{
  // ...
public:
  AudioSample getLoadedSample() const
  {
    return *this; // Slice on purpose to remove load-specific stuff
  }
};
```

That way, use in outside code will just see a well-defined function, with the slicing being just an implementation detail.

Comment: This seems to be the cleanest way to get what I want without having to put a lot of setters in `AudioSample` in order for a outside loader function to be able to fill in it's complex state. So the slicing in and off itself wasn't a problem, just the unintuitive way I was using it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> for each source I derive a class from AudioSample that adds the relevant loader code for the source in question

It actually sounds like that "loader code" should not be there to begin with, or you should overload your construtor/make it more general, or you need a factory or store that "loader code" in `std::function`.

although slicing is defined, it is not common technique, I only fear that other developers will not understand that piece of code in the first glance, which indicates (usually) a poor code. why not write a good readable code from the first place?

Just to share how weird it is for the outside developer, would you also derive and slice `std::string` for every function which returns a string?

Answer (score 0):

How are you going to know which loader code to call? If an object is sliced, one of the things that gets sliced off is polymorphic behaviour - everything behaves like an instance of the base class. And as it's so easy to prevent (pass by reference or a pointer, which is any case probably more efficient in terms of copies being made), it's hard to see why you would ever want to do it.

Comment: I understood the question as "create a loader-specific subclass, do all loading on it, and once loading is done an will no longer be needed, slice it when passing to the rest of the code."

Comment: @Angew What advantages does that gain you?

Comment: Imagine 1. the object is long-lived, and 2. the loading part requires a lot of extra data. The OP's idea is a (rather unorthodox) way of limiting the time the loading-only data occupies memory.

Comment: @Angew "After loading I slice the object on purpose by passing it on to the function that uses AudioSample by value." He now seems to have _more_ data. The original, and the sliced copy.

Comment: But as soon as that passing happens, the loaded original can be discarded.

Comment: @Angew It can't happen as soon as the passing, only after the called function returns. So this still uses more memory than simply passing by reference.

Comment: Yes, this uses more memory *for a while.*